# Update a value in db with the help of the id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this script in codeigniter, and I would like to update the isMultiple column in db based on the question id, how could I do this the simplest?

```
var html = '<div class="question col-lg-12"><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-10">\n' +
                '        <div class="form-group">\n' +
                '    <input name="question[]" type="text" id="input-name" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-alternative" placeholder="">\n' +
                '        </div>\n' +
                '        </div>\n' +
                '        <div class="col-lg-2">\n' +
                '        <div class="form-group">\n' +
                '        <div class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete-question">Remove Question</div>\n' +
                '    </div>\n' + '<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="checkBoxQuestion[]" value="1"><label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Checked</label>'
                '    </div></div></div>';
            $('.append_here').append(html);

function editSpecialization($data){
        $dataInsert = $data;
        $inserted = $data['id'];
        if(@$data['question']) {
            unset($dataInsert['question']);
            unset($dataInsert['id']);
            unset($dataInsert['isMultiple']);
        }
        $checked = (isset($_POST['checkBoxQuestion']))? 1 : 0;
        $this->db->where('id',$inserted);
        $this->db->update('specializations',$dataInsert);
        //if($checked) $this->db->update('isMultiple', 1);
        $this->deleteQuestions($inserted);

        $insert['specialization_id'] = $inserted;
        $insert['sort_nr'] = 0;
        if(@$data['question']){
            foreach($data['question'] as $question){
                $insert['question'] = $question;
                if($checked) $insert['isMultiple'] = 1;
                $this->db->where('id', $inserted);
                $this->db->update('isMultiple', $insert);
                $this->db->insert('questions',$insert);
            }
        }
    }
```

For now, that check inserts me in all the questions

Comment: in your where clause, what is the value of $inserted?

Comment: Is question id.